# How to impose distance constraint without quadratic constraints?

Tags: optimization

I have a set of variables $\{x_i\}$ that I want to optimize according to some objective function. However, I would like that

$$(x_i-x_j)^2 \geq d^2\ \ \ \mathrm{for\ all}\ \ \ i,j$$

Which is a lower bound quadratic constraint, turning the problem non-convex. Is there anyway to formulate this constraint to be convex, for example by reformulating it as an upper bound constraint?

Comment: Are there some other constraints? Do you know anything about the objective function?

Comment: This feels a lot like a sphere packing problem, for which I'd be surprised to see a convex formulation. For example, the Kissing Number problem is still open for $n>4$... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number

Comment: Is CS SE the best SE site for this question?